# "Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s)" with Pandoc

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, mla-style

I'm trying to use Pandoc to generate an MLA-styled paper from a Markdown document, with LaTeX as an intermediary.

Everything is working perfectly so far (well, for PDF output, anyway)—except the Works Cited page, which is completely empty.

I'm using `pandoc --verbose paper.md.txt --template mla.tex -s -S -o "James Edington EH105 Paper 1.pdf"`

My template `mla.tex` is so (templated off [the instructions from Ryan Aycock's `mla-paper`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mla-paper) as well as [Jackson 13's `mla13.sty`](https://github.com/jackson13info/mla13/blob/master/mla13.sty)):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{$bibliography$}
\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{$author_firstname$}{$author_lastname$}{$instructor$}{$class$}{\today\\Word Count: $word_count$}{$title$}
$body$

\nocite{s11}
\pagebreak
\begin{center}
Works Cited
\end{center}
\printbibliography
\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

and `paper.md.txt` is structured so:

```
---
title: 'Maslow and Mandel: Needs hierarchy and human priorities in _Station Eleven_'
author_firstname: 'James'
author_lastname: 'Edington'
instructor: 'William Wilkerson'
class: 'EH 105'
word_count: '311'
bibliography: 's11.bib'
---

_"Survival is insufficient"_, the motto emblazoned…
```

and `s11.bib` consists of just this:

```
@book{s11,
  author    = {Emily St. John Mandel},
  title     = {Station Eleven},
  publisher = {Vintage},
  year      = 2015,
  month     = 6,
  isbn      = {0804172448}
}

@article{maslow,
  author = {Abraham Harold Maslow},
  title = {A Theory of Human Motivation},
  journal = {Psychological Review},
  year = {1943},
  volume = {50},
  number = {4},
  pages = {430-437},
}
```

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

The full output log of the command is at http://pastebin.com/rR5pxGag, but the relevant section seems to be:

```
No file input.bbl.
```

(Which, I imagine, is what's leading to the subsequent errors `LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography`, `LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references`, and `Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):`)

I have tried `backend=` `bibtex`, `bibtex8`, and `biber`; the error message does not change substantially.

So, what do I need to do to get Pandoc to feed a `.bib`* file into `\printbibliography`?
*(* I am 100% OK with converting this file into other formats)*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't use pandoc, so perhaps disregard my comment, but the problem appears to be that there is no bbl file. Have you tried manually running `bibtex` by hand? Failing this latex the document first, then run bibtex and then pandoc? (Quite likely, your`backend=...` commands should do this but they don't seem to be working...)

Comment: @Andrew If I run `bibtex s11.bib` I get an error `I couldn't open file name \`s11.bib.aux'`

Comment: Well, you do not run bibtex on the bib file, but on the tex file (without extension).

Comment: I thought you needed to call `pandoc` with some bibliography-related commands to get a bibliography. Something like `--biblatex --bibliography=s11.bib`. (I always forget because I don't use `pandoc` except for rather simple tasks....)

Comment: @TeXnician My tex file is just a template. I feed the markdown into it; I'm writing in markdown. The tex file as-is doesn't have citations in it. And @jon that command didn't work; I got the same `No file input.bbl` error again.

Comment: Well, but while doing the PDF generation (or whatever) Pandoc generates a LaTeX file you have to run bibtex/bibtex8/biber on. Usually the options jon provided should do that.

Comment: @TeXnician However, the commands jon's recommending aren't working—that is why I posted this question. I even shared my code I was using, just in case someone can get it to "Works On My Machine", which would at least be a start so I can figure out what I'm doing wrong that this isn't working.